# Formula to calculate round-trip travel time based on current distance to far-away galaxy

Tags: cosmology, expansion

Cross-posted from Physics Stack Exchange - [original](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652106/formula-to-calculate-round-trip-travel-time-based-on-current-distance-to-far-awa)

The question was closed as HW-like there.

#### The Premise

You travel at a constant velocity towards a far-away galaxy. You then travel back at the same velocity. How long will have passed for the people on Earth? Answers must take into account the expansion of the universe.

#### Definitions:

- now is defined as 21st century

#### Parameters:

- Time from now you will depart (in years)
- Distance away that the galaxy is now (in light-years)
- Velocity (in % of light-speed)

#### Output:

- number of years that will have passed on Earth between the time you depart and the time you get back

This was inspired by this question: [At 50% c, I go party to IC1101 galaxy, and back home. How many times can i go before the expansion of the universe will lock me on one side?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588745/at-50-c-i-go-party-to-ic1101-galaxy-and-back-home-how-many-times-can-i-go-be/)
.

#### Significance

This will allow for many different astronomical calculations by moving the elements of the formula around (eg. how long until we won't be able to communicate with a distant galaxy?).

Comment: Please let me if know if this should be moved to Space Exploration.

Comment: Just a quick note: Cross-posting is discouraged on Astronomy SE.

Comment: @fasterthanlight I thought it would be fine as the question is no longer open on Physics SE.